# USB Audio Dongle for Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: sound, 13.10, usb, adapter

I just converted another user to Ubuntu, but unfortunately her onboard sound is currently non-functioning due to a long standing bug, so I'm hoping someone can suggest a cheap USB audio dongle that is known to work with 13.10. I'd get the Penguin one, but it's a bit on the expensive side for only casual use, especially considering most can be had for a couple of quid. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using one of these, and it works wonderfully with 13.10.

I've been an audio hobbyist for 50 years, and a computer guy for 40.  These days, I read reviews a lot, find out what chip the best few use, and then look for the cheapest thing online with that chip.  This uses the TI PCM2704 chip, which is classic.  Build quality is pretty good, metal case with screws, built like a tank actually.  No driver needed, no cables or manuals provided. Needs a classic USB-a cable, which I had a pile of anyway. I got mine for 18 USD delivered, and it really sounds a lot better than any of the cheaper alternatives.

Google "ELE EL-D01" for alternative sources, or "PCM2704" for other versions.

http://www.ebay.com/itm/ELE-EL-D01-MINI-HIFI-USB-PCM2704-DAC-BOARD-CARD-ELNA-Capacitor-New-/120985506266

All best.

Comment: Thanks for that, but to be honest it might be overkill since all she's got is a single low quality speaker, and AFAIK it's only for watching occasional YouTube videos. I don't suppose you're aware of any cheaper options?

Comment: Just had a brain wave, and checked Amazon since the reviews often mention Linux compatility. Got lucky with the [first result](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Dynamode-USB-Sound-Card-7/dp/B003QADH9C/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1388936304&sr=8-1&keywords=usb+audio+adapter). Thanks again for your help.